# Convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am writing a programm for creating schedules for a bunch of users.
Now I have a controller called AddTermineController which should allow the end-user to create a schedule for another user and also a database connection class for schedules.
When trying to save the schedule I am getting this error:

> java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

This is out of the database class where I have created the statements:

```
public void addTermin(Termin terminXL) throws ParseException {
    try {

        PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(ADD_TERMIN);
        stat.setInt(1, terminXL.getUserID().getValue());
        stat.setString(2, terminXL.getUserNameT().getValue());
        stat.setString(3, terminXL.getKommentar().getValue());
        stat.setString(4, terminXL.getKategorie().getValue());
        //TODO von und bis in einen Datum umwandeln um es in die Datenbank einzuspeichern


        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        Date datumVon = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(terminXL.getVon().getValue());
        Date datumBis = (Date) simpleDateFormat.parse(terminXL.getBis().getValue());

        stat.setDate(5, datumVon);
        stat.setDate(6, datumBis);
        stat.setString(6, terminXL.getBis().getValue());
        stat.setString(7, terminXL.getReferat().getValue());

        stat.executeUpdate();
        log.info("Neuer Termin angelegt");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the error code I am given:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)     ...
>   48 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot
>   be cast to java.sql.Date  at
>   de.dpma.azubidpma.dao.TerminDAO.addTermin(TerminDAO.java:82)  at
>   de.dpma.azubidpma.view.AddTermineController.saveButton(AddTermineController.java:79)
>     ... 58 more

If you need any other code brackets let me know, I will update this post as quick as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sd = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
```

Comment: can you elaborate what to do next then?

Comment: @kinansaeb this will convert util date to sql date (from Fri Oct 13 14:24:58 IST 2017 to 2017-10-13). you mentioned how to convert from util to sql date. these 2 lines will convert

Comment: thanks got it working.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html and `java.sql.Date` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).